# Is it possible to mark a comment as unread?

Tags: support, global-inbox

A user has responded to my comment to their question. I did click on the `recent inbox message` and read the comment.

I am currently working on something else and unable to assist the user right now. I would like to come back later, today or tomorrow to the comment.

However, I am quite likely to forget so I was wondering if there is any way I can mark that read comment as unread so that next time I open Stack Overflow I see an unread comment.

Comment: There isn't a way, but you can Favorite the question as a way to notify yourself to return later.

Comment: that would mean i would have to make it a point to check my favorites everyday to make sure i don't have anything left over from the last time i was here. Can we not have something akin to gmail and mark it unread or star it to make it stand out? Could this be a feature request?

Comment: That request already exists: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64283/enable-marking-a-response-as-unread